# How to create one CA to all organisation using crypto config tool

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I am using the cryptogen tool to generate the organisation keypair, I observe that when the I create multiple organisation cryptogen tools  generate different CA private key for each organisation. Lets say i want only one CA for multiple organisation where i need specify it. Below is my config file

```
-Name: Org3
Domain: org3.example.com
EnableNodeOUs: true
Template:
  Count: 2
Users:
  Count: 1

-Name: Org2
Domain: org2.example.com
EnableNodeOUs: true
Template:
  Count: 2
Users:
  Count: 1

-Name: Org3
Domain: org3.example.com
EnableNodeOUs: true
Template:
  Count: 2
Users:
  Count: 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@fama,

It's not possible, by the cryptogen

by default, every organization will have its own CA

No way, if it is the case then there is no point of authorization

Every organization should have its own CA